# Get emails from custom and sent mail folders in c# using Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to retrieve emails from multiple folders including Inbox, Sent, and some custom folders.  I'm first filtering the folders so I can loop over them, calling `FindItems` to return their contents.  The code below works without `searchFilter4` (line 10), but with it I get this unhelpful error:

```
'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException' in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll
```

My code:

```
// Folder name filter for Inbox, Completed, Inprogress, and Sent folders:
SearchFilter searchFilter1 = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "Inbox");
SearchFilter searchFilter2 = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "Completed");
SearchFilter searchFilter3 = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "In Progress");
SearchFilter searchFilter4 = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(, WellKnownFolderName.SentItems);
SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilterCollection = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or);
searchFilterCollection.Add(searchFilter1);
searchFilterCollection.Add(searchFilter2);
searchFilterCollection.Add(searchFilter3);
searchFilterCollection.Add(searchFilter4);

// Find folders:
FindFoldersResults findResults = service.FindFolders(
        WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, searchFilterCollection,
        new FolderView(int.MaxValue) { Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep }
);
```

Comment: You have an empty argument here: `new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(, WellKnownFolderName.SentItems);` Not sure if that's causing the problem or not though.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out while writing my question...

All I needed to do was add the folder to my `findeResults` after calling `FindFolders` with this line:

```
findResults.Folders.Add(Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.SentItems));
```

My new code:

```
// Folder name filter for Inbox, Completed, Inprogress, and Sent folders:
SearchFilter searchFilter1 = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "Inbox");
SearchFilter searchFilter2 = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "Completed");
SearchFilter searchFilter3 = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.DisplayName, "In Progress");
SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection searchFilterCollection = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.Or);
searchFilterCollection.Add(searchFilter1);
searchFilterCollection.Add(searchFilter2);
searchFilterCollection.Add(searchFilter3);

// Find folders:
FindFoldersResults findResults = service.FindFolders(
        WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, searchFilterCollection,
        new FolderView(int.MaxValue) { Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep }
);

// Add SentItems to the findResults:
findResults.Folders.Add(Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.SentItems));
```